# The length of the derivative operator Derivative[0,0,2,0] in \ f^(0,0,2,0)[x,y,z,t] is not the same as the number of arguments. >>

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve Maxwell's wave equation but am faced with an error message

```
DSolve[{Laplacian[{f[x, y, z, t], g[x, y, z, t], h[x, y, z, t]}, {x, 
     y, z}] == -\[Mu] \[Epsilon] D[{f[x, y, z, t], g[x, y, z, t], 
      h[x, y, z, t]}, {t, 2}], {f[x, y, z, 0], g[x, y, z, 0], 
    h[x, y, z, 0]} == {0, 0, 0}, 
  D[{f[0, 0, 0, t], g[0, 0, 0, t], h[0, 0, 0, t]}, t] == {Sin[t], 0, 
    0}}, {f, g, h}, t]
```

The length of the derivative operator Derivative[0,0,2,0] in (f^(0,0,2,0))[x,y,z,t] is not the same as the number of arguments. >>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told `DSolve` that `x, y, z` are constant. (That is, you've told `DSolve` that there is exactly one non-constant variable, `t`.) You should put `x, y, z` in the variable specification along with `t`.